# Extract string in between single quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

```
$String="The failing subtask was: 'Regenerate both backup and primary keys for job scheduling Service Bus namespace'"
```

Output- Regenerate both backup and primary keys for job scheduling Service Bus namespace

the failing subtask was: is fixed it will come in every string message

Comment: I don't understand : _"the failing subtask was: is fixed it will come in every string message"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the fact you've got :

```
$String="The failing subtask was: 'Regenerate both backup and primary keys for job scheduling Service Bus namespace'"
```

You can try :

```
(([regex]".*'(.*)'").Matches($String))[0].Groups[1].Value
```

It use the Matches method on Regex to extract the value of the second group of the first match (you should use `try ... catch` aroud that)